# Trying to fix multiple SQL queries in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-optimization

I have a page that loads 300+ jobs for a cabinetry builder/installer.  I load all their active jobs onto one page, per factory, of which they have three-- Dallas, Arlington, and Aubrey. Each factory has 300 to 400 active (scheduled, unininstalled jobs).

So, when I load the Dallas page, I go over each day, and output the jobs in order for that day.  The queries are repeating for about 50 days. I want to know if I can send this info to the cache somehow.

Here's a picture of what a few days look like...

[image: partial results pictured]

For each day I make 2 SUM queries for the header, and another query to filter jobs for that given day, i.e., 
`@jobs.where(calendar_date: '2016-04-06').each do`

Here are the precise queries

```
# ALL jobs (in the controller)
@jobs = Job.where( active: true, scheduled: true,
              manufacturing_location: session[:factory]).
              includes(:installer).
              order('calendar_date asc')

# Jobs for one day (in the view
@jobs.where(calendar_date: day).order(:calendar_order).each do

# The helper method for the 'daily tabulations' in the header
  = daily_tabulation(@jobs.where(calendar_date: day))

  def daily_tabulation(jobs)
    total_boxes = jobs.sum :number_of_cabinets
    complete    = jobs.where(complete_in_shop: true).sum :number_of_cabinets
    to_build    = total_boxes - complete
    "To Build: #{to_build}, Complete: #{complete}, Total Boxes: #{total_boxes}"
  end
```

These pages take 4 to 7 seconds to load in the browser, even using redis fragment caching.  Granted, each of these 300+ jobs get JS event handlers to drag-n-drop the jobs around on the schedule, as well as JS tooltips, but I'm hoping I can clean up these queries and shave a second or more from the response time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with one collection in this case, you can once load your `jobs`, and then process it like array:

```
@job_by_day = @jobs.select { |j| j.calendar_date == day }
```

And use `Enumerable#sort` instead of `AR#order`.